# Keyboard coveres iAd, how fix?

Tags: ios, autolayout, iad

I made a post a week or two ago and so far nobody has an answer, so I'm going to try another approach. When I use canDisplayBannerAds on an iOS view controller a banner ad is displayed at the bottom. This is useless for my apps since the keyboard is present at all times and it covers the iAds. I also cannot just add an iAd in InterfaceBuilder since I don't always want ads to be displayed and adding them in InterfaceBuilding breaks auto layout if you remove them. Therefore, how on Earth do I display a banner advert that isn't covered by the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know when is the keyboard appear and in that momento set the frame of your iAd.
So, here is the code.
First you need to  implement the observers:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                         name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                       object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                         name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                       object:nil];
```

and the methods that want to execute when apears:

```
    - (void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notification{
    // Here we will set the frame of the banner at the top of the keyboard


        if (_bannerIsVisible)
         {

         [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
         // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
         banner.frame =CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-266, 320, 50);

         [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    }

    - (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *) notification{
    // Here we will set the frame of the banner at the bottom of the view
        if (_bannerIsVisible)
         {

         [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
         // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
         banner.frame =CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-50, 320, 50);

         [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    }
```

Maybe you need to adjust the size or the animation to look good.
Sorry for my english hope this help you.